# Can anybody identify this smelly succulent?

Tags: identification, succulents

[image]

It looks like it may be a type of Crassula. The leaves have a strong menthol/eucalyptus smell. The smell comes from oily hairs on the leaves similar to scented geraniums.

[image]

The underside of the leaves has very prominent veins.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is Plectranthus tomentosa, sometimes called the Vicks plant because it smells a bit like Vick mentho rub, or of menthol/eucalyptus anyway. Some cultural info about this plant here, if you need it

http://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/go/123089/#b

Comment: Yes that's the one

Comment: @NickCollier then accept bamboo's answer. click the checkmark below the vote count